# When doing calculations regarding diodes (in half wave rectifiers), is the peak value of the sinusoidal source used, or is the rms value used?

Tags: diodes

For example, in Vdc = 0.318Vs, is Vs the peak voltage, or the rms voltage. Likewise, how is the PIV determined, e.g. in part (e) of this question:

> 4.65 Consider the half-wave rectifier circuit of Fig. 4.21(a)
>   with the diode reversed. Let vS be a sinusoid with 12-V peak
>   amplitude, and let R = 1.5 kΩ. Use the constant-voltagedrop
>   diode model with VD = 0.7 V.
>
> > (a) Sketch the transfer characteristic.
> >     (b) Sketch the waveform of vO.
> >     (c) Find the average value of vO.
> >     (d) Find the peak current in the diode.
> >     (e) Find the PIV of the diode.

[image: Fig. 4.21a]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework question without any own attempt to solve it.

Comment: the question is just an example. I do not need a solution of it. My main question is that in questions such as these, is Vrms used or Vpeak used.

Comment: Question clearly states "Let vS be a sinusoid with 12-V peak amplitude"

Comment: @Finbarr So we use the peak value in all the calculations? When I had asked this question to an instructor, he had told me to first convert the input into an rms voltage, and then use it to calculate the Vdc.

Comment: If you are doing DC calculations, consider RMS values and for AC calculations, consider peak values.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, in Vdc = 0.318Vs, is Vs the peak voltage, or the rms voltage.

You are saying **DC**, this means that the signal will **never** change. This also means that the \$V_{rms}\$ is **the same** as \$V_{peak}\$.

Or am I misunderstanding your awkward equation perhaps?

Perhaps you mean \$V_{DC} = 0.318 × V_s(t)\$, in this case, \$V_s(t)\$ is AC if understand it correctly, in order to turn it into DC you need to use the RMS value.

\$V_{DC} = 0.318 × \frac{12}{\sqrt2}\$ V.

I'm not sure where you are going to use this \$V_{DC}\$ since it's not asked of you in the question anywhere.

Some extra info regarding RMS. If you'd use an AC voltage source of \$100×\sin(t)\$ V to power a 60 W lamp, then you could instead use a DC voltage source of \$\frac{100}{\sqrt2} ≃ 70.7 \$ V. The lamp will consume 60 W if it's being fed a 100 V sine wave, or a 70.7 V DC voltage.

---

> Likewise, how is the PIV determined, e.g. in part (e) of this question:

Regarding PIV, which stands for Peak Inverse Voltage. That means what is the maximum voltage across the diode in the *reverse* direction?

Well that would be 12 volt, assuming \$V_s(t) = 12\sin(t)\$.

It would occur when \$\sin(t) = -1\$ => \$V_s(t) = -12\$ V

Comment: Yeah, that was what I meant. I apologize for the ambiguous equation.